# Kotlin: resolve generic inheritance

Tags: android, kotlin, moxy, android-moxy

After reading same articles I still cannot solve generics problem:

I have BaseActivity:

```
abstract class BaseActivity : MvpAppCompatActivity(), BaseView {
    abstract fun getPresenter():BasePresenter<BaseView>
}
```

BaseView interface for it

```
interface BaseView : MvpView
```

And for sure BasePresenter

```
open class BasePresenter<T : BaseView> : MvpPresenter<T>()
```

Then I create BaseConnectionView

```
interface BaseConnectionView : BaseView
```

And BaseConnectionPresenter

```
class BaseConnectionPresenter<T : BaseConnectionView> : BasePresenter<T>()
```

So when I create BaseConnectionActivity

```
abstract class BaseConnectionActivity : BaseActivity(),BaseConnectionView {
    override abstract fun getPresenter(): BaseConnectionPresenter<BaseConnectionView>
}
```

I have error:

```
Return type is BaseConnectionPresenter<BaseConnectionView>, 
which is not a subtype of overridden 
public abstract fun getPresenter():BasePresenter<BaseView>
```

But **it is** subtype!

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: "But it is subtype!" It isn't, https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html explains why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was easier than I think if use star-projections

So in BaseActivity I replaced

```
abstract fun getPresenter():BasePresenter<BaseView>
```

To

```
abstract fun getPresenter():BasePresenter<*>
```

And then I can just override it with new presenter, like

```
override abstract fun getPresenter(): BaseConnectionPresenter<*>
```

Answer (score 1):

`BaseConnectionPresenter` is a subtyp of `BasePresenter<T>` with `T: BaseConnectionView`. The function `getPresenter` only returns `BasePresenter<BaseView>`. There's a problem because `BasePresenter<T>` is not garanteed to be `BasePresenter<BaseView>`. The following fixes it:

```
class BaseConnectionPresenter<T : BaseConnectionView> : BasePresenter<BaseView>()
```

Comment: Well in that case I have same error when I have something like class:RealPresenter : BaseConnectionPresenter<SomeView>()

Comment: Also impossible to correctly use viewState in Moxy from BaseConnectionView if you pass BaseView to BasePresenter